# how can i use sleep function in python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, sleep

### executor.py

```
from time import sleep
if __name__ == "__main__"
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    sleep(1)
```

### starter.py

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

if __name__ == "__main__"
    process = Popen(['python', 'executor.py'], stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    while process.poll() is None:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        print(output)
    process.wait()
```

### in Shell

```
python starter.py
```

after command execute result like this
    #after 10 scecond later....
    0
    1
    2
    3 
    4 
    5 
    6 
    7 
    8
    9
    i want print number each one scecond
    how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard output is buffered. You should flush the buffer after each `print`:

```
from time import sleep
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: If this is Python 3, you don't need to explicitly call `sys.stdout.flush()` at all, you can just change the `print` to `print(i, flush=True)` and it will perform both printing and flushing as a single call.